# How do I append data in columns?

Tags: c++, fstream

The following code appends the values of y[i] in the same column as x[i], y[0] starting underneath x[10]. I would like to append the values of y[i] in the second column next to the first column of the values of x[i]. Could you please help me how to do this?

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  ofstream outfile;
  double x[10], y[10];
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    x[i] = i+10;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    y[i] = i-10;
  }
  outfile.open("result.txt", ios_base::app);
  outfile << "loop: " << 1 << endl;
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  outfile << x[i] << "\n";
  }
  outfile << "loop: " << 2 << endl;
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    outfile << y[i] << "\n";
  }
  outfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `x[i+1] = x[i+1] + y[i];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
outfile << "loop: " << 1 << endl;
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   outfile << x[i] << "\n";
 }
```

To-

```
outfile << "loop: 1 \t loop: 2"  << endl;
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
outfile << x[i] << " \t "<<y[i]<<"\n";
}
```

No need for

```
outfile << "loop: " << 2 << endl;
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  outfile << y[i] << "\n";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  ofstream outfile;
  double x[10], y[10];
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    x[i] = i+10;
    y[i] = i-10;
  }

  outfile.open("result.txt", ios_base::app);
  outfile << "loop: " << 1 << endl;
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      outfile << x[i] << ' ' << y[i] << "\n";
  }
  outfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: the first two for loops can be reduced to one for loop.

Comment: This works perfect too. I couldn't upvote your answer because I am a  new member in this forum and I don't have enough reputations. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @user3328741 it's okay as long as you got your answer.